# ¿Cómo se hace un array de objetos para luego emplear el Arrays.equals?

Tags: java, poo

1. ¿Cómo lleno un array de objetos?
2. ¿Cómo uso el `Arrays.equals`?

En el `main` hago dos arrays y los trato de llenar pero la respuesta es: (en el final)

> ***(claramente ya puse los get y set de cada uno, solo que seria demasiado largo el código y por eso los borre)***

```
    package Edible_ingredients;
    import java.util.*;
    enum Categorias{vegetales, proteinas, carbohidratos};
    public class Edible_ingredients {
 
    private String cod;
    private String nombre;
    private int calorias;
    private Categorias Categoria;
    
    
    public Edible_ingredients() {
        
    }
    
    public Edible_ingredients(String cod,String nombre, int calorias,Categorias Categoria) {
        this.cod=cod;
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.calorias=calorias;
        this.Categoria=Categoria;
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Edible_ingredients[] arr1= new Edible_ingredients[1];
        Edible_ingredients[] arr2= new Edible_ingredients[1];
        
        arr1[0]= new Edible_ingredients("1234", "pan", 10, Categorias.carbohidratos);
        arr2[0]= new Edible_ingredients("1234", "pan", 10, Categorias.carbohidratos);
        boolean answer2=Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2);
        System.out.println("arr1 y arr2: "+answer2);

     }
}
```

> ***respuesta:*** arr1 y arr2: false
> y debería de ser true ya que puse exactamente los mismos valores de cada variable...

> Y tampoco sé si así se debe de llenar un array o no?

Comment: No creo que se pueda comparar dos objetos, ya que cada uno cuando se instancia tiene una codificación diferente para cada uno, prueba a comparar el mismo objeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > ¿Cómo uso el Arrays.equals?

Déjame decirte que el código está correctamente bien. Lo único que le faltó fue sobrescribir el método `equals`.

Como la clase `Edible_ingredients` en ningún momento sobrescribe el método `equals`, usa el `equals` que heredó de la clase [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) (cualquier clase creada en Java es una subclase de `Object`). El problema es que el [método equals](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java) de la clase `Object` es implementado de esta forma:

```java
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
}
```

Así que el resultado en este caso será `false` porque estarías comparando las referencias de dos objetos y por ende, dará `false`. Ya que una *referencia* no es más que el identificador del objeto y su característica es que debe ser único.

**Solución:** Simplemente sobrescribe el método `equals` en la clase `Edible_ingredients`:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    Edible_ingredients ei = (Edible_ingredients)o;
    return ei.cod.equals(cod) && ei.nombre.equals(nombre) && ei.calorias == calorias && ei.Categoria == Categoria;
}
```

De este modo, el método [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) de la clase `Arrays` no invocará el `equals` de la clase `Object`, sino, el que hayas sobrescrito.

> > ¿Cómo lleno un array de objetos?

Déjame decirte que ya has llenado el *array* de objetos.

Comment: y qué es el Object o ? que quieres decir con que es una subclase...                              y en sí qué es la "o" porque no tengo ningún objeto que se llame o ? como funciona ?

Comment: @DeborahMizFel La clase `Object` es la superclase. En Java, por defecto, cualquier clase que vayas a crear, heredará los atributos y métodos de la clase `Object`. Se le llama una **subclase** a una **clase**, cuando esa clase hereda cosas de otra clase. En este caso la clase `Edible_ingredients` hereda los métodos de la clase `Object`y por ende, será una **subclase** o **clase hija** de `Object`.

Comment: Con respecto al `Object o`, en ese parámetro se guarda la referencia del objeto con el que quieres comparar. Tu le puedes poner el nombre que sea.

Comment: Si, ya me funciono, muchísimas gracias.                                                   
Y publique otra pregunta sobre lo mismo pero usando el polimorfismo, a ver si crees que  me puedas ayudar, porfa.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar este template en el objeto para implementar `equals()` a partir de los atributos del objeto:

```
public class Edible_ingredients {
    private String cod;
    private String nombre;
    private int calorias;
    private Categorias Categoria;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // self check
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        // null check
        if (o == null)
            return false;
        // type check and cast
        if (getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        Edible_ingredients item = (Edible_ingredients) o;
        // atributos
        return Objects.equals(cod, item.cod)
                && Objects.equals(nombre, item.nombre)
                && calorias=item.calorias
                && Objects.equals(Categoria, item.Categoria);
    }
}
```

La implementación predeterminada del método equals se define en la clase Java.lang.Object que simplemente verifica si dos referencias de Objeto (digamos `x` e `y`) se refieren al mismo Objeto. es decir, comprueba si `x == y` (por ello te da `false` ya que son dos objetos creados aparte).

Para este caso, deberias implementar esto mismo en la clase `Categoria`.

Cabe destacar que `equals()` debe implementar las reglas indicadas en la documentacion: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-